# compare $cov(aX, bY)=ab \;cov(X, Y) $to $Var(abX)$ using the marginal distribution $f_X(x)$

Tags: probability

I am trying to compare the proof $cov(aX, bY)=ab \;cov(X, Y)$ (which I have already found) to $Var(abX)$ using the marginal distribution $f_X(x)$. I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

$Var(abX)=E[(abX)^2]-[E[abX]]^2 = (ab)^2\left(\int x^2 f_X(x)dx - \int x f_X(x)dx\right) = (ab)^2Var(X)$

Of course, $Var(Z)=Cov(Z,Z)$ so you can get there via that route, but that doesn't require the marginal distribution.

Comment: +1. Which shows that the PDF $f_X$ is offtopic to prove this.